# UILongPressGestureRecognizer in Spritekit and Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am a complete newbie to programming and I am trying to learn how to make a simple iOS game using Spritekit and Swift 4.

So far, I have achieved some mild success, but I would like to add some further details to the game to make it a little more playable.

I have added some actions to my GameScene so that when the user taps the screen, a Sprite execute an action. It works fine, but now I want to keep **repeating that action if the user holds its finger on the screen**.

I have read some posts about it, but they all seem to point to Objective-C or earlier versions of Swift that just pop a bunch of errors when testing and I am unable to get them working for me.

I know I am supposed to be using some instance of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer) seems rather confusing about how to initialise it or what to declare on `action: Selector?`

As I understand it, in my `viewDidLoad` I must include something like:

```
let longTapRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")
self.addGestureRecognizer(longTapRecognizer)
```

And then write a function (I am not sure if inside `viewDidLoad` as well) that handles the action:

```
func handleLongPress(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        print("Long press")
    }
}
```

As easy as this may sound, I simply cannot seem to understand how the `action:` is supposed to be declared or how to solve this.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544406/swift-4-unrecognized-selector-setting-up-a-gesture-recognizer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for the action in swift is `#selector(methodName(params:))`

(See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective_c_runtime_features_in_swift)

Your gesture recognizer would be written as such:

```
let longTapRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
  target: self,
  action: #selector(handleLongPress(recognizer:)))
```